# Check the time when the EBS Volume becomes available

Tags: amazon-web-services, persistent-volumes

May be a simple question, but it is there a way to check when the EBS Volumes become unattached/available.. We could see the creation date, 
but is there a way to check when its last detached from Instance or when its state changed from "in-use" to "Available"?

I am planning for a Script based on it.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe you have a single API that will give you that history. You need to use a combination of `describe-volumes` CLI and cloudtrail CLI to get this.
What you need to do is first get all the available volumes using this command.

`aws ec2 describe-volumes  --filters Name=status,Values=available`

And then for each available volume list down all the events from CloudTrail using this CLI.

`aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=ResourceName,AttributeValue=vol-xxxxxxxx`

Unfortunately the current CLI cannot have multiple lookup attributes. However, you can still filter this futher for Detach events using this.

`` aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=ResourceName,AttributeValue=vol-08324aae5b496fdfc --query 'Events[?EventName==`DetachVolume`]' ``

If you have to have logic based on these you can potentially have Cloudtrail events sent to a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS CLI you can get the required details.

e.g. If its EBS volume mounted on EC2

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes
```

This will give you AttachTime, VolumeId, InstanceId etc and more details

Further CLI reference and examples can be found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html

Comment: I wanted to know when it's detached from the instance. I mean, when it becomes available.  "aws ec2 describe-volumes" doesn't give this.

Comment: You could monitor the status of the volumes
aws ec2 describe-volume-status --volume-ids vol-xx

And, if the status' is impaired or busy or something besides ok. You can infer it as an unhealthy or detached time.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volume-status.html

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have s script triggered by the event of an EBS volume becomes available you can get [status change event from CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#ebs-event-types). See also [event example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-cloud-watch-events.html#volume-events) to filter the status you need.

You can trigger AWS Lambda or send an SNS/SQS message based on this event.